# react-select how to make a pre selected fixed options

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I want to make a pre selected options that cannot be deleted based on w. whether a client has been visited or no, here is what I want to achieve [image]

```
const { clients } = this.props.clients;

const listOfClients =
  clients !== null &&
  clients.clients.map(client => ({
    value: client._id,
    label: client.company
      ? client.company
      : client.lastname + " " + client.lastname,
    last_visit: client.last_visit,
    wilaya: client.wilaya,
    visited: client.visited // true : false
  }));
```

and that's how i render my select options

```
<Select
          name="clients"
          isMulti
          value={this.state.clients}
          onChange={e => this.onChange(e, "clients")}
          isClearable={this.state.clients.some(client => !client.visited)}
          options={listOfClients || []}
          className="basic-multi-select"
          classNamePrefix="select"
        />
```

and my state holds an array of clients as follows :

```
[{value: "5c0e784f0249ea83d88bddf3", label: "sarl medic", visited: true}]
```

if visited = true , then this selected option must be greyed out and cannot be deleted. I've looked up [this example](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/docs/examples/FixedOptions.js) but i don't understand where i went wrong. Thank you :)

Comment: can you create a demo. Probably clients state in not ordered correctly in your case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `listOfClients` options are missing the important `isFixed`, it should be the same value as `visited` if I understand your code correctly.

Also with multi select you will need to disable manually the remove function like the following code:

```
const listOfClients =
  clients !== null &&
  clients.map(client => ({
    value: client._id,
    label: client.company
      ? client.company
      : client.lastname + " " + client.lastname,
    last_visit: client.last_visit,
    wilaya: client.wilaya,
    visited: client.visited,
    isFixed: client.visited // true : false
  }));

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      clients: []
    };
  }

  onChange = (e, option) => {
    if (option.removedValue && option.removedValue.isFixed) return;

    this.setState({
      clients: e
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Select
          name="clients"
          isMulti
          value={this.state.clients}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          isClearable={!this.state.clients.some(client => client.visited)}
          options={listOfClients || []}
          className="basic-multi-select"
          classNamePrefix="select"
          styles={styles}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/x3kq4mo5m4).

Comment: Thank you so much @Laura .. and sorry for the late reply I have just seen your answer